# Why Java is giving me two different errors in two different envirnonments, even though the (simple) code is the same?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have this simple code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte a = 10, b = 20, c = a+b;

          System.out.println(a);

    }

}
```

This is of course an error. But if I compile the code with an online editor (such as JDoodle) I get this input, which is the one I expect:

```
  error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
      byte a = 10, b = 20, c = a+b;
                                ^
  1 error
```

Otherwise, if I compile the code with Eclipse (2018-12) + JDK:

```
  java version "1.8.0_231"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

I get this different error:

```
   Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte
```

How is it possible? I think the first error is the right (expected) behavior. Should I think there's a problem in my jdk?

Comment: If they're different versions of the compiler they could easily produce different error messages. Not sure why you would think it is a problem. They both agree it is an error.

Comment: `cannot convert from int to byte` and `possible lossy conversion from int to byte` is the same error. You could even combine them as `cannot convert from int to byte [because it would result in] possible lossy conversion [from int to byte]`. The first error message just states the problem, while the second error message includes a reason for why it's a problem. --- Similarly, `incompatible types` and `Type mismatch` is the same, just phrased differently.

Comment: It's the same problem, with a different error message from different compilers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My issue comes with the certification part. I know you have to be very precise in doing the certification, so I didn't think Java errors could be different by chaning compilers. So Type mismatch IS THE SAME as lossy conversion? It could be, but type mismatch to me feels more like WRONG type assignment, like String to int, or boolean to String, not compatible types with different ranges. 

However, I don't understand why I get negative votes. Mine is a question about Java that could be helpful for developers, a tip/suggestion in general. Why should it be downvoted..?

Comment: "Type mismatch IS THE SAME as lossy conversion" a lossy conversion results from type mismatch; a type mismatch isn't necessarily a lossy conversion. If you are concerned about knowing the error messages for a certification exam, I think it's safe to say that JDoodle isn't "canonical".

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular error message mandated by the Java Language Specification. The specification simply says things like (all examples from [JLS Chapter 14](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html), but similar examples can be found throughout the spec):

> It is a compile-time error if final appears more than once as a modifier for a local variable declaration.
>
> It is a compile-time error if T is the null type.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the name of a label of a labeled statement is used within the scope of the label as a label of another labeled statement.

The specific rule that generates your compiler error is in [JLS 15.26.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1):

> If the type of the right-hand operand is not assignment compatible with the type of the variable (§5.2), then a compile-time error occurs.

Compiler implementors are free to put whatever message they think is useful. Count yourself lucky they don't just say: `Erk!`.